# Purchase Order - How to replenish stock in NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

NopCommerce is primarly focussed on the sale of goods, and it does have some stock management.  How would be the best way, i.e. is there a way, to do the stock replenishment in a more formal method like Purchase Order.  Could create a plugin, but I was hoping for something more "built in".  The internet is rife with reference to purchase order, but that is more for the benefit of the customer at point of order creation, i.e. "their internal reference".

Comment: I'm having confusion with *replenish stock* and *purchase order*. As per as I know, *purchase order* is something to place order behalf of customer..but how could you relate it with *stock replenishment* ?

Comment: @Div Traditionally, Sales Order is for selling to the customer and Purchase Order is to buy from your Supplier (thereby replenishing stock).  When a customer buys from your shop, they may be replenishing themselves and may often be raising  a purchase order on their side.  I just wanted to have a document process (like an invoice) to follow the store replenishment - other then just updating the product onhand qty.  Imagine you have a online store and you have to keep physical stock.  At some point you need to raise a purchase from your supplier.

Comment: Okay, but there is no _built in_ functionality to create a doc. format for stock replenishment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question, as @Div already said, there is no "built in" feature in nopCommerce to generate for you a purchase order document.

but to give you the closest "built in" feature for that purpose, you can try this workarounds.

1) navigate in admin to the Low stock report /Admin/Product/LowStockReport you can get a list of all products with low stock, but you cant export that as a document, but you can print the page if that helps.

2) you can set all your products to send you a notification when it reaches a certain amount, navigate to the product, and fill in "Notify for qty below" field.

but to really fulfill your needs, you will need to create a plugin for that.